# raw textarea in new page (similar to github) with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure why I have not managed to find the answer on stackoverflow but, as an exercise in learning, I have a html page with a textarea and a button (#button1) to save the content. That works perfectly.

I have a second button:

```
    $("#button2").click(function(){
    var textcontent = $('textarea#mytextarea').val();
```

Button2 gets the content from the textarea and can display it to console.

***My question:***

How can I use a button - like github - that would display the raw text only? Even when I strip all the html, etc, and append with `<pre>`, a wget retrieval still has all the code from the page.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you give an example of the content in the textarea, and the current result vs. desired?

Comment: it is unclear where / how the textarea content is saved, and how exactly you're trying to retrieve it... it would also be useful to understand what you exactly do to strip html and at which stage...

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, that little jquery bit copies the content of the textarea (regardless of what it is). Your solution below by the way is fantastic but I suspect I need to do more work to generate a new link because I had hoped to retrieve these notes with wget (hence without the html overhead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by creating a new window and keeping a reference to it and then inserting HTML to it.

```
// 1. create a new window
var new_window = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));

// 2. Insert the HTML into the newly created window
// assumption: the textarea contains the text '<p>Hello World!</p>'; you can easily add it here by concatenation: '<pre>' + textarea_content + '</pre>';
new_window.document.body.innerHTML = '<pre><p>Hello World!</p></pre>';
```

Recommended reading:

- [`Window.open()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
- [`Element.innerHTML` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)